# Will installing Ubuntu on the C drive delete data on the D and E drives?

Tags: 18.04, lts

I want to completely migrate from Windows 10 to Ubuntu.  I am going to perform a clean install of Ubuntu onto the C drive.  I want to confirm that this will not erase my media files (audio, video, images) on the D and E drives.

Comment: When you install to C then D and E are left untouched.

Comment: Be sure during the installation process that you install the system in the right partition, of course.

Comment: WARNING! depends on the option you pick. You need to pick "something else" and pick the c drive yourself where you do not format d and e partition. If you pick "replace" and there is only 1 windows d and e get formatted.  Mind also that it is bad practice to have windows partitions with no windows: at some point in time the disks will get a problem with the filesystem where you will need windows. next: always make a backup. alternative: if d and e are actual disks disconnect the cable during installing.

Comment: Listen to @Rinzwind - that advice may save you money, time, and frustration. Those four words alone: "ALWAYS MAKE A BACKUP" is some of the best advice you will ever receive. Installing a new OS is inherently risky, and a wrong selection can indeed ruin your day - backups before starting are cheap, easy, and fast.

Comment: You can always unplug the drives, install, then plug them back in.

Answer (score 0):

During installation from a USB stick, select a partition for the Ubuntu Installer to know where to install. Only the place you select will be overwritten. If you select the C: drive, D: and E: will be unaffected.

Best you click "Something Else" to create or select the partitions you want. If these D: and E: are physical hard drives, it is wise to remove them if you are not entirely confident you will do the right thing during installation.

Comment: and make a backup prior to messing with partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If your disk(D: and E:) is different physical hard drivers. Please remove it. 
Because. Windows is Virtual disk management system. But Linux is document management system. 
If your C: D: E: is a logic disks. Linux perhaps wise your data.